# QEMU: how to create a 486 VM without fpu

Tags: qemu, x86-emulation

I'm trying to create a VM of a 486 without FPU, like the 80486SX. I figured this could be accomplished with QEMU. I couldn't find the possibility to directly specify such a cpu (there's only the option `-cpu=486`). Based on the documentation, I thought it would be possible to remove the FPU by specifying the cpu as follows

```
qemu-system-i386 -cpu 486,-fpu (...)
```

But after I installed Debian 5.0 (the last Debian to support the 486), `cat/proc` tells me that a FPU is indeed considered present (even though it's not in the flags), and gcc will emit floating point instructions for a simple hello-world style program printing doubles, and QEMU will happily execute it.

```
user@debian-486-nofpu:~/$ cat /proc/cpuinfo 
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 4
model       : 8
model name  : 486 DX/4
stepping    : 0
cache size  : 0 KB
fdiv_bug    : no
hlt_bug     : no
f00f_bug    : no
coma_bug    : no
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : no
cpuid level : 1
wp      : yes
flags       : pse
bogomips    : 466.94
clflush size    : 32
power management:
```

Comment: But Linux kernel emulates FPU when it's not present, so it shouldn't make much of a difference for a user running Linux except possibly for speed (though FPU is not much faster than emulation).